# Algún algoritmo más correcto para esto (Java)

Tags: java

Necesito que mi aplicación desactive o active un botón si existe algo en mi jTextField, pero no se si usar estos eventos son correctos, pd. con el keyTyped no me funciona ya que me lee la cadena sin un caracter, por lo tanto cuando solo tiene una letra no lo acepta.

```
public void validateData(){
   if (!txtTournamentName.getText().isEmpty() && 
                               !txtTournamentName.getText().isBlank()) {
        btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
    } 
}

private void txtTournamentNameKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                              
    validateData();
}                                             

private void txtTournamentNameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
   validateData();
}
```

Comment: java tiene un evento change?

Comment: @gbianchi No, pero me diste la idea, ya le agregué un change listener al botón, muchas gracias.

Comment: listo genial agrega una respuesta ompleta!!!! mira [answer]